# How to rendering index.html from a directory in github pages

Tags: github, hosting, github-pages

I have the below presented directory structure in a gitHub repository.

```
|- /project-folder
  |- readme.md
  |- /ui
    |- index.html
    |- css //folder holding css files
    |- javascript //folder holding js filesr code here
```

The issue am having is trying to displaying the index.html on gitHub pages instead of using **readme.md** which is located at the root of the repository/directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `index.html` should be in root.
I have a simple example myself for your reference. https://github.com/chuanjin/mqttc

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in other words index.html most be in the root folder right?

Comment: yes, you should have index.html in the root, which means you need to reorganize the structure of your code, and probably solve the links/refs in the files.